# Memory leak using structs

Tags: c++, memory, struct, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak from the following code:

```
  mat operator*(mat A,mat B) {
  mat C;
  int r,c;
  C.ncol = B.ncol;
  C.nrow = A.nrow;
  C.val=(datatype**)malloc(sizeof(datatype*)*C.nrow);
  if (C.val==0) {
    printf("ERROR: malloc failed in 'mat operator*(mat A,mat B)', #1\n");
    C.nrow = 0;
  }
  for (r=0; r<C.nrow; r++) {
    C.val[r] = (datatype*)malloc(sizeof(datatype)*C.ncol);
  }
  /* matrix multiplication calculations */
  return C;
}

int makemat(mat *A,mat B) {
  int i,j;
  if ( ((*A).nrow!=B.nrow)||((*A).ncol!=B.ncol) ) {
    printf("ERROR: incompatible matrix dimensions for A=B.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  for (i=0; i<(*A).nrow; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<(*A).ncol; j++) {
      (*A).val[i][j].tblflg = B.val[i][j].tblflg;
      memcpy(&(*A).val[i][j].tname[0],&B.val[i][j].tname,namelen-1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  mat A;
  mat B;
  mat C;
  mat D;
  for (i=0; i<1e8; i++) {
    /* I've tried doing D = A*B;
       (makemat(&C,D)) { /* printf error */ }
       but that doesn't work either
    */
    if (makemat(&C,(A*B))) { printf("i: %i\n",i); return 1; }
  }
  printf("i: %i\n",i);
  return 1;
}
```

The code terminates at i=907174.  I get a malloc failure in the `operator*(mat A,mat B)` function, which I'm assuming is due to a memory leak (task manager shows memory usage at the maximum).  Can anyone explain why there is a memory leak (assuming that is in fact the prolem)?  Do I have to free any of the `mat`s A,B, or C?  Does the `mat` that is returned from the `operator*` operation ever get freed, and could that be my problem?  Thanks for any help!

EDIT: sorry forgot the makemat function.  It has been added in above.

EDIT2: I've tried to take out the details and make it more succinct. The only function that I can tell that is continuously allocating memory is the operator* function.  What is happening with the return memory and how could I free it (if that is indeed what is causing the leak - as David alluded to in his answer)?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org).  You will probably discover the problem in the process of doing so.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `malloc`, `free` and `memcpy` in C++; always use `new`, `delete` and `std::copy`.  And really, you should be using containers (e.g. `std::vector`) instead, as they manage memory automatically.

Comment: what is the `makemat` function?

Comment: I don't see any declaration code for your makemat function

Comment: There's nothing C++ in this question, why is it tagged as such?

Comment: @enobayram: I was about to comment that before, but operator overloading is not available in C, so I guess that makes it C with operator overloading... I mean C++ or C-- or the like

Comment: @enobayram - `mat operator*(mat A,mat B)` is all I've spotted, but that is not C

Comment: ah, I've seen it now. Calling it C-- is very snappy I think, because a mixture of C and C++ programming is inferior to both.

Comment: Please quit tagging this `c` -- `mat operator*(mat A,mat B)` is _clearly_ not valid C code.

Comment: @Oli, what do you mean minimal test-case?  I

Comment: @Jade: Read the article I linked to in my previous comment.  Basically, if your code snippet is more than 10-15 lines, you haven't worked hard enough to isolate the problem!

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit the enter key... I'm not sure I can take anything out of question. Aside from being poor programming, what is making the memory leak?  I've never had "official" programming lessons, but I'd like to know what is going on with this particular problem so I can become a little more knowledgable.

Comment: @Jade: You definitely can take stuff out, and you should (the etiquette on Stack Overflow is to present the smallest possible piece of code).  Start by removing some of the struct fields; most of them are probably irrelevant.  After each edit, try re-running to ensure that the problem still exists.  Keep stripping stuff out until you're left with a 10-line test-case.

Comment: @Oli, I did read the link in your first comment, but I don't see how I could reduce it and still have all the necessary information (i.e. all the functions that are relevant).

Comment: The only function that is not "necessary" in the code is the freemat() function, but I was hoping through discussion that that function could be used to solve the memory leak.

Comment: @Jade; Are you saying that if you remove *any* of those struct fields, then the problem goes away?

Comment: @Oli, if I remove any of the structs, the program won't run at all.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the purpose of this forum is.  I thought I should post all the relevant code so more knowledgable programmers can trace the problem through the code...I understand it should be as short as possible, but if not all the information is presented then that makes it hard to answer the question.

Comment: Since this is a question about memory, I figured any functions that allocate memory or show the structure of the variables should be included.

Comment: @Jade: No, Stack Overflow is not a place to find other people to debug your code.  The general idea is that you should do as much work as you possibly can to solve your own problem first (by simplifying the code, using the debugger, etc.).

Comment: @Oli, I'm not looking for someone to debug the code, I'm looking for someone who could explain source of the memory leak; perhaps "The mat returned from operator* gets stuck in limbo since freemat isn't called on it" - or whatever the issue really is. By providing all the functions, it can be narrowed down to that.  I'm not looking for my code to work, I'm looking for help from someone who can explain why it doesn't work, so I don't make the same mistake next time.

Comment: @Jade: But for someone to do that, they either have to read all your code and figure out what it does in their head, or they have to copy-and-paste into an IDE, compile it, and then start debugging it.  It's your job to do the narrowing down.

Comment: @Oli, haha, I wouldn't have taken the time to type all that into the question if I didn't have to.  I don't know what else to check, which is why I posted the question.  Would it have been simpler to ask "What happens to the memory from the return of operator*"?  I apologize if what I thought was necessary to answer the question is overly superfluous (or the question was posed poorly).

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no call to `free_mat` in the code, the obvious answer is that yes, you have a memory leak. I can also assume that you are not calling `free_mat` on the argument of `makemat`, which means that the memory obtained inside `operator*` will be leaked. Either that or else somewhere else in the only function that you did not provide which incidentally is what you are calling in the loop you are leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your `operator*` declaration, you allocate memory for a member of the local struct variable, `C`. This creates memory leak as this allocated memory is not accessible once the `operator*` function returns. A solution would be to allocate this memory outside this function and pass the allocated memory to the function for the operations to be done over it. The other solution would be not to use dynamic memory allocation.

All that said, as suggested in the comments your safest bet would be to forget about pointer allocation, while coding in C++. Use containers with automatic memory allocations.

Comment: `C` is returned, so that memory is not lost *there*. Most probably it is lost later on, but there are no memory issues (just bad design) in the provided `operator*`